# Using a jquery plugin with es6 import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import rangeslider into an es6 class using import, however it always returns `rangeslider is not a function`

```
import * as rangeslider from 'rangeslider.js';

export class Layout {

    testFunc() {
        $(".rangepicker").rangeslider({
            onSlide: function(position, value)
            {
                $(this).parent().find(".rangepicker-output").html(value + 'px');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The below is `rangeslider.js`'s source code, that do not offer es6 modular support. It support AMD and CommonJs,but not es6.

```
function(factory) {
'use strict';

if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
} else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
}
```

The es6 modular is like:

```
export default function foo() {
  console.log('foo');
}
```

Comment: CommonJS exports are handled by Webpack. NPM packages don't have to be ES modules to be imported in transpiled application.

Comment: The question's desc does not indicate that use webpack. If use webpack to packaging,the infomation for the question is too few, you need offer the webpack.config.js

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to import exported value from jQuery plugins because they conventionally export jQuery instance.

The fact that imported `rangeslider` isn't used in code eliminates it from transpiled code, the package is not imported at all.

It should be

```
import 'rangeslider.js';
```